# Php page not loading when using session variable to determine form action

Tags: php, session, variables

I am relatively new to the form, so sorry if I make a mistake in posting.

```
<?php

require_once("login/include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("./login/login.php");
    exit;
}

include 'menu.php';

$is_student = $_POST["is_student"];

//echo "<br/> student $is_student <br/>";

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Seat Selection</title>
<link href="xampp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>
<?php
if ($is_student == "no") {
  $student = FALSE;
  $_SESSION['student'] = FALSE;
} elseif ($is_student == "yes") {
  $student = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['student'] = TRUE;
} else {
  echo "Please select Student or Parent before making reservation.";
  die();
}

if ($student)
  echo "Student Reservation";
else
  echo "Parent Reservation";

?>
</h1>
<h2>Step 1 of 2: Select Seats</h2>

<table>

<?php if ($student) { ?>
  <form name="seats" action="confirms.php" method="POST">
<?php } else { ?>
  <form name="seats" action="confirm.php" method="POST">
<?php } ?>

<?php


        $all_seats = $fgmembersite->GetAllSeats($student); // it's a 2 dimensional array $list[row][col]
                                               // the value of which is another array with seatid and whether it's
                                               // filled or not
        $reserved_seats = $fgmembersite->GetAllReservedSeats($student);

        //var_dump($reserved_seats);

        // merge the reserved seats into all seats
        foreach ($reserved_seats as $r => $arr) {
          //echo "R =$r <br/>";
          //var_dump($arr);
          foreach($arr as $c => $seatid) {
             //echo "R = $r, C = $c, S = $seatid><br/>";
            $all_seats[$r][$c] = array(seatid => $seatid, filled => TRUE);
          }
        }

        foreach ($all_seats as $r => $c) {
          echo $r. ">";
          foreach ($c as $value) {
            if ($value['filled']) {
              echo "x";
               } else {
              echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"seats[]\" value=\"$value[seatid]\"/>";
            }
          }
          echo "<br/>";
        }
?>

<input type="Submit" name="SeatsSelected" value="Select Seats">
</form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use the boolean value from $student to determine which confirmation page it goes to, but when I load the file the code is in (seats.php), it doesn't load. It acts like the page is missing from the web directory. Any idea what's up? This might just be my bad coding.

Comment: There is not enough info to get idea of whats going on. From where comese `$student`? Its from `$_POST`? What does mean `missing from the web directory`, error 404? Please provide more details.

Comment: You shoul post non-ambigious code for us to help you solve your problem . It that info is the only thing you can give were just more likey guessing ...

Comment: just added the whole file. $student comes from a session variable I know is working since the echo function works. The page doesn't give a 404 error. just shows up blank.

Comment: wheres the make_reservation.php file content.. because thats suppose to be where you go when you submit the form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php if ($student) { ?>
  <form name="seats" action="confirm.php" method="POST"> 
<?php } else { ?>
  <form name="seats" action="confirms.php" method="POST"> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this worked, it was a silly bracket problem. looks like i just needed an extra pair of eyes. thanks.

Comment: No dear you no need extra pair of eyes , anyone can do mistake because we are men not god.